# What alterations do I need to make for my Flask python application to use a MySQL database?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite, flask

I am new to developing applications, and I have been trying to familiarize myself with doing so with Flask. I followed their great tutorial and read their equally-detailed documentation to create my first basic app which uses a SQLite3 database.

To accomplish this, and per their instructions, I imported the following:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from contextlib import closing   

import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
     abort, render_template, flash
```

and have a file `schema.sql` set up with the following to configure the database:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  title string not null,
  text string not null
);
```

I access the database using commands that again came from the [Flask site tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/views/#tutorial-views). I am under the impression that I need to, when creating applications where users create and manage their own accounts, implement a MySQL database instead. This being the case, what sorts of things about my database-related code do I need to change? I am sure there is quite a large difference between working with these two databases, so any point of reference – suggestions of tutorials to follow or documentation to read – would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not going to answer your question directly, but instead I'll give you a nice alternative to your current approach.

Instead of manipulating the database using SQL, why not take the OOP approach with [SQLAlchemy](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/quickstart.html)?

Here's a rough translation of your current code:

```
# ...

from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///path/database.db'
#app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/database'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Entry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Text)
    text = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, title, text):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text

    def uppercase(self):
        self.title = self.title.upper()
        self.text = self.text.upper()
```

Notice how the data structure doesn't depend upon the database. You can switch from SQLite to MySQL by just changing one config string.

Initializing your database is just as simple:

```
$ python -c "from your_app import db; db.create_all()"
```

Working with the database is even simpler:

```
entry = Entry('test', 'entry')
entry.uppercase()

db.session.add(entry)
db.session.commit()
```

Just a suggestion.

Comment: Greatly appreciate it! That is indeed a simple transition. I will read up on what you described including what you provided, and I thank you for noting the easy switch, particularly how to initialize and work with the db.

Comment: @zch: No problem. Flask is pretty fun to work with once you set everything up. Good luck!